# How to set the parent of a control at design time

Tags: .net, vb.net

I spent hours searching and am surprised to be unable to find anything on this.  I have a form with several panels and a couple of splitters.  I would like to cover half the screen with a container to aid in debugging.  The container should be on top and have the form as the parent.  However this seems impossible to do.  It seems no mattter what combination of resizing, moving or BringToFront I use the IDE insists on sticking the container into a panel.

Is this something that must be done in code?  Is there no way to just draw a container on the screen and have it on top of everything?

No WPF, just basic windows.

Comment: Are you using XAML/WPF?

Comment: Have you looked at the code in the .designer.vb file?  or would you prefer to do this via drag/drop or copy/paste?

Comment: No I haven't looked at the code in the designer.  I just thought it odd that I can't draw a control on top of panels without it getting set inside a panel (and obscuring some of the container).  I thought there may be some keystroke or property I can use.  I can fix it with code but just wanted to know if there was something I was missing.

Comment: The designer parents new controls to whatever surface you click to begin drawing.  You can drag a control between containers.  If you have part of the form surface visible you can drag your container to that open place on the form to reparent it.. or just begin drawing on the open space.

Comment: Thats good to know.  That is also probably the root of the problem since there is no open space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From within Visual Studio, follow these steps:

1. Click on View menu
2. Click on Other Windows
3. Click on Document Outline

Your should see this editor:

[image]

Use the horizontal arrows to move the controls into or out of parent containers.